# How to filter table through checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, razor-2

In my Razor view I have a table with 3 non displayed properties. `Id_Loaction`, `Id_Level` & `Id_Section`

Above this table I have 3 lists of checkboxes for every location, level & section with the appropriate Ids as the value.

```html
@foreach (var section in Model.Sections)
{
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: data" value="@Html.Encode(section.Value)"/>@Html.Encode(section.Text)
    </li>
}
```

Note: `section.Value` is the ID of the element which is also used in the table rows

The table itself is fairly simple built:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Offers) 
{
    <tr data-bind="visible: data.IsChecked == true ">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section.Text)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section.Value)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section.IsChecked)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Sections));

    function FormViewModel(data) {
        this.data = ko.observableArray(data);
    }

    window.viewModel = new FormViewModel(data);

    console.log(viewModel.data());    
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

/edit:
I have updated the code to my actual mess. The Model.Sections is a ViewModel, which is identical to the ViewModel used for Model.Offers.Section. Both contain a Value, Text and IsChecked property.

How can I compare both those and display only the table rows on which the section is checked?

Please go slow on me. 
Kind regards

Comment: You want to filter client side or server side?

Comment: I'd love to filter clientside, but since I have no idea where to start, I'll take whatever I can get, as long as there are no page refreshes

Comment: In that case you should show how your page is setup.  How is your table being generated?  You tagged knockout, so are you using a `foreach` binding?  Maybe put together a little jsFiddle and that will make it very easy for someone to help you out.

Comment: I have mentioned knockout, because I have some very basic  experience with it and have seen some awesome results done with it. 
So in essence: somebody unchecks location Simbabwe (id4) and every row where the location id 4 is present has to be hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an attempt at using knockout with a trimmed down version of what i am assuming Serv is trying to do.  This is an example of a simple filter on a list of objects and can easily be expanded to include more filters and more complex models.

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/zTRq2/3/

Simple Filter ViewModel:

```
function filterViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.text = ko.observable(data.text);
    self.checked = ko.observable(data.checked);
}
```

Trimmed down Offer View Model:

```
function offerViewModel(offer) {
    var self = this;
    self.description = offer.description;
    self.location = offer.location;
}
```

Main View Model:

```
function FormViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    // map data from server to locations filter
    self.locations = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.locations, function (filter) {
        return new filterViewModel(filter);
    }));

    self.offersView = ko.computed(function () {
        // get list of offers that were passed in, we'll manipulate filteredOffers from now on
        var filteredOffers = data.offers;

        // get all selected locations view models
        var selectedFilterLocations = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locations(), function (location) {
            return location.checked();
        });

        // run through util function to filter only offers that match any selected location
        filteredOffers = ko.utils.arrayFilter(filteredOffers, function (offer) {
            var matchesLocation = false;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(selectedFilterLocations, function (location) {
                if (offer.location === location.text()) matchesLocation = true;
            });
            return matchesLocation;
        });

        return filteredOffers;
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<!-- list of location checkboxes -->
<ul class="unstyled inline" data-bind="foreach: locations">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked" /> <span data-bind="text: text"></span>

    </li>
</ul>

<!-- table which is bound to the offersView computed observable -->
<!-- offersView is recalculated everytime a selection changes from the filter list -->
<table class="table-bordered">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: offersView">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: location"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have to check your solution later. I am completly used by a different project right now.

Comment: this looks excatly like what I am looking for, but where do I inject my serverside model into the js code?

Comment: This line is giving me trouble: `if (offer.location == location.text()) matchesLocation = true;`
It works in your fiddle, but if I console.log(offer.location) it is always undefined.

Comment: If I take if `(offer.Section.Text == location.text()) matchesLocation = true;` it should work, but I am getting the error: `Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: description is not defined;
Bindings value: text: description `
Like I stated earlier: offer.location is undefined (it is section or department for better understandment) According to my server side model. offer.Section.Text is the value which has to be compared, but lets me run into binding erros.

Comment: the `Unable to parse bindings` error is typically because the current context does not contain a property called `description`.  In my fiddle, i had an offerViewModel that had a property called `description`, if you came up with a different model with a different property name, then the `data-bind="text: description"` would need to be updated to match that, replacing `description` with whatever variable you want to use.  could you post what you have to a jsfiddle?

Comment: with regards to how to inject your server side model, you would want to  do something like `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` which will encode your model data as JSON, which can then be passed in to the viewmodel;

Comment: Gosh ... Major brainlag on my side. I just updated the data-bind values to reflect my serverside model (where your values before) to correct strings and it works. I am offering another bounty and mark your answer as correct. (Bounty in 23 hours)
I will be extending the model for the other 2 checkbox lists tomorrow thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use jQuery's each unless you have to.

knockout provides your view the foreach method.  Use that and an if statement or a visible binding.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: entity">
    <!-- ko if:checked() -->
         <!-- display your Li here -->
         <li></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </ul>
```

alternatively you can remove the ko if container less statement and use the following instead

```
 <li data-bind="visible: checked()"></li>
```

but remember both of those tests are saying if checked equals true.  If your value is a string you will need to test against a string.

**Edit**

if you have some id or value to test against you can do it like this -

```
<li data-bind="visible: section.checked() === true"></li>
```

or some other logical test

Answer (score 2):

You need to set style of tr to be none if its checked (set to non 'none' value if want to show only checked one), thats all 
Eg:

```
var viewModel= function(){
var self=this;
self.tableData=ko.observableArray(),
init=function(){
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        //Put all your data here
        var data={
            selected:ko.observable(false),
            id:ko.observable('loc'+i),
            desc:'desc'+i
            };
        self.tableData.push(data);
    }
};
init();
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

then HTML is like

```
    <div data-bind="foreach:tableData">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:selected"/><span data-bind="text:id"></span>
    </div>

   <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Desc</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:tableData">
        <tr data-bind="{style:{display:selected()?'none':''}}">
            <td data-bind="text:id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:desc"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

here is the jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Dhana/keT7B/

Comment: You could also just use ```visible: selected()```. It does the same thing.

Comment: yes, the updated jsfiddle with visible is here : http://jsfiddle.net/Dhana/keT7B/1/

Answer (score 1):

By "row" I assume you mean li. The `each()` method that is part of the jQuery library is used for iterating through an array, in this case an array of matched elements returned by the jQuery selector `$('input[type="checkbox"]')`.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if(this.checked)  
        $(this).closest('li').hide()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sailorob/4bC2P/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

If you:

1. give an id to ul containing the checkboxes
2. give an id to the table
3. use some convention for a tr css class that includes the id

then you can - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzned/4/):

```
$('#sectionslist input').change(function() {
   $('#offersTable .offerId' + $(this).val()).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you just want to do some simple client-side filtering? Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzul1983/e6ADe/2/

Since there will be many sections, it's not ideal to hardcode them in JS. Instead, you could use .NET to output them in the TR element.

e.g. (if you use my fiddle)

`<tr data-bind="visible: isChecked('@Html.Encode(item.Section.Value)') ">`